# Add an array as a subdocument to a Mongoose model instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am building an array with data and want to push that array to sub-document.

```
var pubArray = [];
var count = 5
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  pubArray.push({publicationName: req.body.publicationName[i], dateSent:req.body.dateSent[i]});
};

Students.findOne({studentNumber: filter}, function (err, student) {
  student.publications.push({pubArray});
  student.save();
});
```

If I use the `{publicationName: req.body.publicationName[i], dateSent:req.body.dateSent[i]}` inside the `student.publications.push` it works fine.  If I try to push the array, nothing happens.

Comment: Please, post your model definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `.push()` method in mogoose works just like it's JavaScript equivalent in that it is "pushing" a single element onto the array, rather than a whole array. So you can either assign the whole array or just construct in the loop:

```
 student.publications = pubArray;
```

or:

```
// Construct with .push in loop:
Students.findOne({ "studentNumber": filter },function(err,student) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < count: i++ ) {
        student.publications.push({
            "publicationName": req.body.publicationName[i],
            "dateSent": req.body.dateSent[i]
        });
    }
    student.save(function(err) {
        // Complete
    });
});
```

But really you would be better off using an "atomic" operator of [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) with [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) in a direct update. This is then just one trip to the server, rather than two:

```
Students.update(
    { "studentNumber": filter },
    { "$push": { "publications": { "$each": pubArray } } },
    function(err,numAffected) {

    }
);
```

That is generally worlds better than the "find/modify/save" pattern, and not only in being more efficient, but it also avoids potential conflicts or overwriting data since the object and array is modified "in-place" in the database, with the state current to the time of modification.

Atomic operators should always be favoured for the performance benefits as well as lack of conflicts in modification.

Comment: Thanks that worked great.  I will keep in mind the atomic operators.

Answer (score 0):

The `publications` property of the `student` object is an Array. You can simply assign this property to the `pubArray` created earlier:

```
Students.findOne({studentNumber: filter}, function (err, student) {
  student.publications = pubArray;
  student.save();
});
```